# How to update UI multiple times after delay in response to a single user action(onTap)

Tags: flutter

I was able to accomplish this by using an async method embedded inside the state object of the stateful widget. But I am not able to accomplish this when using provider (I am open to using Riverpod or Bloc or any other state management framework). Below is the code which loops through multiple times and updates the state at each stage. I am calling this code in the OnTap method of a datacell like this:

```
callAdjCellOps().then((opsResult) {}).whenComplete(() {
                inProgress = false;
              }).catchError((e) => print(e.toString()));
```

Method being called:

```
  Future<OpsResult> callAdjCellOps() async {
    for (int i = opsResult.referenceRow; i < SAMAlgorithm.rows; i++) {
      if (opsResult.result) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: calculateDelay(i)));
        setState(() {
          opsResult = samAlgorithm.adjacentCellOperation(_gameArray, _chosenColumn, opsResult.referenceRow);
          if (opsResult.processRightColumns) {
            //change below flag only if we got true from adjacentCellOperation. We want to do further processing if it is true even once
            processRightColumns = true;
          }

          if (opsResult.processLeftColumns) {
            //same as above..
            processLeftColumns = true;
          }
        });

        if (opsResult.leftCellSame) {
          await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: calculateDelay(i)));
          setState(() {
            samAlgorithm.moveColumnItemsToFillGap(_gameArray, _chosenColumn - 1, opsResult.currentRow);
          });

          await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: calculateDelay(i)));
          setState(() {
            samAlgorithm.addColumnValues(_gameArray, _chosenColumn - 1, opsResult.currentRow);
          });
        }

        if (opsResult.rightCellSame) {
          await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: calculateDelay(i)));
          setState(() {
            samAlgorithm.moveColumnItemsToFillGap(_gameArray, _chosenColumn + 1, opsResult.currentRow);
          });

          await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: calculateDelay(i)));
          setState(() {
            samAlgorithm.addColumnValues(_gameArray, _chosenColumn + 1, opsResult.currentRow);
          });
        }
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      samAlgorithm.processLeftAndRightColumns(processLeftColumns, _chosenColumn, _gameArray, processRightColumns);
    });

    return opsResult;
  }
```